# Script to insert data into tables dynamically using Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

I understand that the documented way to insert data into a table looks like

````
```class Table(db.Model):
       __tablename___ = 'table'
       id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
       data = db.Column(db.String(50)
    ...

    insert = Table(id = '0', data = 'new data')```
````

However, I am working on a project that has multiple tables all with different columns, lengths, and data.  I have worked out how to get the dynamic data into a dict, prepped to create rows.  Below is my actual code:

```
def load_csv_data(self, ctx):
        data_classes = [Locations, Scents, Classes]
        data_tables = ['locations', 'scents', 'classes']

        tables = len(data_tables)
        for i in range(tables):
            with open('./development/csv/{}.csv'.format(data_tables[i]), newline='') as times_file:
                times_reader = csv.reader(times_file, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
                for row in times_reader:
                    data_columns = data_classes[i].__table__.columns
                    columns = len(data_columns)
                    insert_data = {}
                    for col in range(columns):
                        row_key = data_columns[col].key
                        row_value = row[col]
                        insert_data.update({row_key: row_value})
```

The challenge I am having is finding a way to do the actual insert based on these dynamic params.  So if the above returns:

```
insert_data = {val1: val2, val3: val4, val5: val6}
```

I would like to convert this to:

```
insert = Table(val1='val2', val3='val4', val5='val6)
```

Everything I have tried so far has issued a `__init__() missing 2 required positional arguments:`  error.

Anyone have any thoughts on how I might accomplish this?

Comment: Nevermind. I actually found the answer on this thread. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63356749/flask-sqlalchemy-add-row-using-dynamic-column-name

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flask SQLAlchemy add row using dynamic column name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63356749/flask-sqlalchemy-add-row-using-dynamic-column-name)